# Password Problems

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords

Hi I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my piece of code. I am trying to make a password application that, when I click on a button, will open the window to insert a recipe when the two passwords match and if they do not match then it will open a error dialog box. However it keeps coming up with error saying that password is not defined when I try and run it. Please could someone help?

```
def password_screen():

    password = Tk()
    password.title("Password")

    lbl1 = Label(password, text="Please enter the password to access the program's code.")
    lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky=W)

    Label(password, text = "Password").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(password, text = "Repeat Password").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    btna = Button(password, text = "Continue", command=GetValue)
    btna.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5)

    e4 = Entry(password)
    e5 = Entry(password)

    e4.grid(row=1, column=1)
    e5.grid(row=2, column=1)

def GetValue():

    global e4, e5

    e4 = Entry(password)
    e5 = Entry(password)

    pass1 = e4.get()
    pass2 = e5.get()

    if pass1 == pass2:
        btna.configure(command=insert_new_recipe)
    else:
        btna.configure(command=dialog)
```

Comment: `password` is a local variable in `password_screen`. It can't be accessed from `GetValue`.

Comment: What would I do then to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As qwe mentioned, password is local to the password_screen function. One solution would be to add `return password` to the end of the `password_screen` function and then pass it to `GetValue`. I don't think you'd need the `global e4, e5` either. Something like:

```
password = password_screen()
GetValue(password)
```

(As a sidenote,  having multiple naming styles in the same piece of code is confusing to read. It helps to name functions consistently in terms of things like capitalisation and underscores/camelCase)